# How to ignore key value while inserting data to the database in EF Core?

Tags: c#, database, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have to fetch some data from an external API and insert it into my database using EF Core. The data i get as a response is related. I need to use id's (which are also coming to me from an api), to create some relations on these entities. Below i attach snippet with the method responsible for creating these relations:

```
private IList<LeagueEntity> CombineLeaguesWithGames(IList<LeagueEntity> leagues,
        IList<GameEntity> games)
    {
        if (leagues != null && games != null)
        {
            foreach (var league in leagues)
            {
                league.Games = games.Where(g => g.LeagueId == league.LeagueId).ToList();

                foreach (var team in league.Teams)
                {
                    team.HomeGames = games.Where(g => g.HomeTeam.TeamId == team.TeamId).ToList();
                    team.AwayGames = games.Where(g => g.AwayTeam.TeamId == team.TeamId).ToList();
                    team.TeamId = 0;
                }

                league.LeagueId = 0;
            }

            foreach (var game in games)
            {
                game.GameId = 0;
                game.HomeTeam = null; // to avoid repetitions
                game.AwayTeam = null;
            }
        }

        return leagues;
    }
```

As you noticed, i have to set id of every single entity to 0 before inserting it to my database. The reason is, i cannot insert explicit key value to my tables. I don't really like this solution, is there any, more elegant way to ignore id value before insert, and let the database find it while saving changes?? The sql script "SET IDENTITY_INSERT ... ON/OFF" doesn't fit to my problem because only one table can have identity insert turned on at a time, and i need to insert related data.

Comment: Is there any reason you haven't just created the PK with the identity column as your own internalID and saved the provided Ids in a separate column, something like ExternalId?